# Prove that the support function of a closed non-empty set is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, support-function

> Let $C$ be a closed non-empty set, but not necessarily convex. The support function of $C$ is given by
>   $$S(z) = \sup_{c \in C} \langle z,c\rangle. $$
>   Prove that this is a convex function.

**Attempt**

Let $a \in [0,1]$. Then

$$S_C(ax + (1 - a)y) = \sup_{c \in C} \langle ax + (1- a)y,c\rangle \leq \sup_{c \in C } \langle a,c\rangle + \sup_{c \in C} \langle (1-a)y,c\rangle$$

Can I actually break up the sum as $\sup_{c \in C } \langle a,c\rangle + \sup_{c \in C} \langle (1-a)y,c\rangle$? If it is not bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $$ \sup_{x\in A} (f(x)+g(x))\le \sup_{x\in A} f(x)+\sup_{x\in A} g(x)$$
holds in general.

Comment: I thought that's only true (as with equality) if only the set is bounded above.

Comment: It is a simple consequence from $f(x)+g(x)\le\sup_{y\in A}f(y)+\sup_{z\in A}g(z)$ for $x\in A$.

Comment: Oh god, how could I not see that!?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

The supremum of an arbitrary collection of convex functions is convex (this can be seen by noting that the epigraph of the supremum is the intersection of the constituent epigraphs).

Since each function $z \mapsto \langle c, z \rangle$ is convex, it follows that the supremum over all $c \in C$ is also convex.