# Prove support function $f$ is convex and show subgradient

Tags: convex-optimization

Let S be a nonempty, bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ be defined as follows:
$$ f(y) = \sup \{y^T x: x\in S\}. $$
The function $f$ is called the support function of S. Prove that $f$ is convex. Also, show that if $f(y) =y^T x^-,$ where $x^- \in S, \ x^-$ is a subgradient of $f$ at y.

This problem comes from “Nonlinear Programming Theory and Algorithms”.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/689522/173147

Comment: It is $\partial f(x) = \mathrm{argmax}_{z \in S}z^\top x$

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis below is the proof for $\supseteq$. Do you happen to know how to prove $\subseteq$?

Answer (score 1):

You need neither boundedness nor convexity for the claims to hold!

- **Step 1: Convexity.** Let $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t \in [0, 1]$. Then

$$
\begin{split}
f(tx+(1-t)y) &:= \sup_{z \in S}(tx+(1-t)y)^Tz\\
&= \sup_{z \in S}tx^Tz+(1-t)y^Tz\\
&\le \sup_{z \in S}tx^Tz + \sup_{z \in S}(1-t)y^Tz\\
&\le t\sup_{z \in S}x^Tz + (1-t)\sup_{z \in S}y^Tz\\
&=: tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)
\end{split}
$$

Thus $f$, is convex (and this doesn't depend on $S$ is convex / bounded or not!).

- **Step 2: Subgradients.** So, suppose $f(x) = x^Tz$ for some $z \in S$. Lets show that $z$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x$, i.e that
  $$
  f(x') \ge f(x) + z^T(x'-x),\;\forall x' \in \mathbb R^n.
  $$

Indeed, for any $x' \in \mathbb R^n$, one computes

$$
f(x)  + z^T(x'-x) = f(x) + - z^Tx + z^Tx' = 0 + z^Tx' = z^Tx' \le f(x') := \sup_{s \in S}s^Tx'.
$$

Thus $z$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x$, and once again, this doesn't depend on whether $S$ is convex / bounded or not!

Comment: I think the definition of subgradient need S is convex?

Comment: No, definitely not. You can always write down $\{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x') \ge f(x) + v^T(x'-x)\}$ and call it the "subdifferential" (i.e the set of all "subgradients") of $f$ at $x$.